# Bundle exec rake test running fine but rails test fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, minitest

`rails test:integration` , `rails test:controllers` are running fine individually but running `rails test`, it fails throwing an error:

> ActionView::Template::Error:         ActionView::Template::Error: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sprockets.

`bundle exec rake test` also passes all the tests

Comment: Could be a problem with the binstubs ...

Comment: Could you please provide `Gemfile` & test config file?

Comment: @ahmed it started working after i have run rake assets:precompile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after running `rails assets:precompile` not really sure how.